# Styling web applications using Orbeon Forms

Tags: css, orbeon

Let's say I would like to change the color of all `<h1>` elements to red in the Guess the Number sample application. How can I do that with Orbeon Forms 4.0+ CE?

With Orbeon Forms 3.9.0 CE, it's done as follows:

```
<xhtml:head>
  <xhtml:title>Guess The Number</xhtml:title>
  <xhtml:style type="text/css">
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }
  </xhtml:style>
  ...
```

However, when I tried the same with Orbeon Forms 4.5 CE it didn't work anymore:

```
<xh:head>
  <xh:title>Guess the Number</xh:title>
  <xh:style type="text/css">
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }
  </xh:style>
  ...
```

In order to make it work, I had to prepend my CSS rule with `.orbeon` as follows:

```
<xh:head>
  <xh:title>Guess the Number</xh:title>
  <xh:style type="text/css">
    .orbeon h1 {
      color: red;
    }
  </xh:style>
  ...
```

Is this the correct way to apply CSS styles at the moment? Is there a way to do this using "the good old method"? :) The reason why I am asking this is that I am about to update my old Orbeon Forms engine (3.x) to the latest version, as it includes tons of useful improvements (thanks guys!). If CSS rules need to be prepended, I will have to prepend (and possibly rewrite) CSS styles to all of my existing XForms web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 4.0, [Orbeon Forms uses Bootstrap](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/03/announcing-orbeon-forms-40.html). Some users embed the forms produced by Orbeon Forms into existing pages, and wouldn't like the Bootstrap CSS to apply to the rest of the pages. To avoid this, the Bootstrap that comes with Orbeon Forms has been "patched" to add `.orbeon` in front of all the CSS rules. And so Orbeon Forms can more easily override Bootstrap rules when necessary, `.orbeon` has also been added in front of all the Orbeon Forms CSS rules.

As a result, if you want to override a Bootstrap or Orbeon Forms CSS rule, you need to make your selector "stronger", and adding `.orbeon` is one way of doing it. Note that if you're using a preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), doing this for all your rules is quite easy. See for instance [`xforms.less`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/config/theme/xforms.less#L13).

Comment: I see. Are the following two options possible? 1) To remove `.orbeon` in front of all the CSS rules through configuration properties, or maybe by editing some other file in Orbeon? 2) To disable Bootstrap CSS rules completely through configuration properties, or maybe by editing some other file in Orbeon? Then, I would need to either apply my own CSS rules manually to XForms elements or copy ready-made CSS rules from an old Orbeon release (in which file they are located?).

Comment: @mplaine To remove the `.orbeon` in front of the Orbeon Forms CSS, you'd have to change a few `.less` files, and recompile them. And to disable the Bootstrap CSS, you'd have to change Java code (`XFormsFeatures.java`), as Bootstrap is now really required, e.g. to handle help, so you can't just remove it from a property. Honestly, it looks much simpler to just make your own rules stronger.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I ended up to override Orbeon Forms' Bootstrap override CSS rules with my own CSS rules that match default Bootstrap CSS rules :) Anyhow, I think a new configuration property for disabling all Orbeon Forms generated CSS rules (incl. Bootstrap) would be handy. This would allow authoring CSS rules as needed and starting from scratch. It would also help, I guess, to upgrade Bootstrap or change to a different CSS framework.